# std::min, std::max and autoDiff

Tags: c++, autodiff

When implementing the ReLU function for AutoDiff, one of the methods used is the `std::max` function; other implementations (conditional statements) work correctly but a try to implement max functions returns only 0 in the whole range.

On input vector:
`dual in[] = { -3.0, -1.5, -0.1, 0.1, 1.5, 3.0 }`
the derivative call in the form
`derivative(ReLU,wrt(y),at(y))` where `y = in[i]`
gives proper results if ReLU is implemented with:

```cpp
dual ReLU_ol(dual x) {
    return (x > 0) * x;             // ok; autodiff gives x > 0 ? 1 : 0
}
dual ReLU_if(dual x) {
    if (x > 0.0)  {
        return x;
    } else {
        return 0.0;
    }
// ok; autodiff gives x > 0 ? 1 : 0
}
```

that is (regarding derivative) one if x > 0 and zero elsewhere.

When ReLU is implemented in the form:

```cpp
dual ReLU_max(dual x) {
    return std::max(0.0,(double)x); // results an erroneous result of derivative 
}
```

as result, I get zero in the whole range.

I expect that `std::max` (or `std::min`) should be prepared correctly for automatic differentiation.
Am I doing something wrong or maybe I miss understand something?

The resulting plot is:
[image]

where *d / dx* is calculated with AutoDiff; purple and blue lines are overlapping; results for `ReLU_ol` are not plotted.

Comment: I would like to see whole definition of the function (mainly the cv-qualifiers of return type) and how you call it. I suspect. that it is either templated or uses automatic type deduction.

Comment: I completed/edited the question

Comment: What is `dual`? In first and second example you are returning it unchanged, in problematic you construct new from a `double`. Are you sure you are not losing information here?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, so it is two doubles (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) whereas the second part (as far as I understand) is to determine the error (imaginary part) of the calculated derivative at a point. In my tests, I didn't notice a loss of accuracy.
Nevertheless, some way around the problem is that AutoDiff contains its own definition of max/min functions (I didn't notice earlier) ...so I guess the problem is hard to solve within AutoDiff::derivative(?)

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for [autodiff](https://autodiff.github.io/) with forward diff.
Instead of using stdlib, always use autodiff:: internal Functions.
this means using internal structures.

```cpp
autodiff::Vector2real myvec(2);
myvec(0) = 1;
myvec(1) = 0;
return myvec.minCoeff();
```